# Dynamically change schema to accommodate custom fields!

Tags: mysql, schema

I am working on building a sort of a cms for a particular project. Nothing that will have a large volume of records in any table. Within 6 digits max.

I was thinking to create the default schema for all tables but then allow the editors to add custom fields to certain tables by adding fields to the schema. Obviously there would be the option to also drop fields.

I'm not an expert but neither a noob and I am sure I can write the proper codes to not get things mixed up and make a mess of it.

But still would this have any impact on the data integrity if changes are made on populated tables?

What are the hazards I could come across?

Comment: Dynamically adding columns is very silly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model is your best bet

Comment: I have considered EAV but was advised against.

Comment: EAV is a bad thing when you have better choices, it doesn't sound like you do here.

Comment: Why is changing the schema a bad idea? If the data will never be to big to cause huge load and take very long? I need concrete reasons, there are plenty reasons pro and con EAV. I do not like the cons as they would give me to much of a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a presentation about the various solutions to support custom fields:

- [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling).

The most straightforward option for greatest compatibility with SQL, including constraints and data types, is just to add columns as needed. But I would caution to *not* let users do this, instead let them submit a request and the DBA can perform the operation. A good tool to reduce impact is [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Other solutions include:

- [EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) (but before you try it please read the article [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/), and my blog post [EAV FAIL](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2009/05/eav-fail.html))
- [Class table inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
- [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html) with [Inverted Indexes](http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql)
- [NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/) document-store solutions

Comment: So you agree schema change can be a good solution if done properly?

Comment: Yes, the best implementation for custom schema extensions that I remember seeing is in Bugzilla, the old Perl bug-tracking app. You can add columns, and also add code in a separate directory to work with those columns.

Comment: Like the comparison from hierarchy types (in your book) i like especially the "summary comparison" table

Answer (score 1):

Don't use EAV. There's no integrity and it's hard to query.

Your best bet is either to simply change the database schema, or to use LOB fields, such as XML or JSON. These are what Martin Fowler recommends:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html

Comment: So, how is the integrity achieved with XML or JSON columns?